# Using EF6 with .Net 5

Tags: entity-framework, .net-5

is it possible to use different database platforms (SqLite, PostgreSQL, MariaDB) with .Net 5 and Entity Framework 6 similar to .Net Core?

When I try to install the NuGet packages I get an error (is not compatible)

Desperately trying to find a start and can't get any further!?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are there any particular reasons for not using EF Core 5 with .NET 5?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean?

Comment: Yes for example in ef6 you can pre generate views which should be a good performance improvement if you have many entities related to each other etc